# How do I change the color of the text-item in a menu bar using PySide6/PyQt?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside6

I have a small example where a button creates a menu. When the button is pushed it's creates menu (Red,Green,Blue) and I configured with a stylesheet. But, these doesn't work. I expected the menu-item in "red","green" and "blue".  What is wrong?

BTW: I checked [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524274/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-a-menu-bar-item-in-pyqt5), but is there more efficient way?

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QMenu
class MainWindow3(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Click here for Menu", self)
        self.menu = QMenu(self)
        action1 = QAction("Red", self)
        action2 = QAction("Green", self)
        action3 = QAction("Blue", self)
        action1.triggered.connect(lambda: self.change_button_color('red'))
        action2.triggered.connect(lambda: self.change_button_color('green'))
        action3.triggered.connect(lambda: self.change_button_color('blue'))
        self.menu.addAction(action1)
        self.menu.addAction(action2)
        self.menu.addAction(action3)
        self.button.setMenu(self.menu)
        self.change_button_color("red")

        # Stylesheets for the menu
        self.menu.setStyleSheet("""
            QMenu::item {
                color: black; /*default color */
                background-color: gray;
            }
            QMenu::item:selected {
               background-color: yellow;
            }
            QMenu::item[text=="Red"] {
                background-color: red;
            }
            QMenu::item[text="Green"] {
                background-color: green;
            }
            QMenu::item[text="Blue"] {
                background-color: blue;
            }
        """)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def change_button_color(self, color):
        self.button.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {color};")
        self.button.setText(f"The color is {color}")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow3()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: QMenu does not support per-item styling.